# Get previous and current state in Redux's reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I start to study Redux.
In my app i have a button. I push in this btn and get an object.
This object income to reducer in `action.payload`.
Object change everytime, when i push in the button.
How i can save all previous state in reducer, and add the current state?
To make something like that:

```
 if (action.type === "ADD_ITEM") {
        return {
          items: [all previous state, + current state],
        };
      }
```

All code in reducer

```
const initialState = {
  items: [],
};

const basket = (state = initialState, action) => {
  if (action.type === "ADD_ITEM") {
    return {
      items: [action.data],
    };
  }
  return state;
};

export default basket;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to *append* new data into an array you can shallow copy the existing state array and append the new data to the end.

```
const initialState = {
  items: [],
};

const basket = (state = initialState, action) => {
  if (action.type === "ADD_ITEM") {
    return {
      ...state,         // shallow copy existing state
      items: [
        ...state.items, // shallow copy existing items
        action.data,    // append new data
      ],
    };
  }
  return state;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the prev value before updating it (and you can save it), and as you know you can update it with an action